# Convert some code to a string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to convert following line to a text, but it does not work, please help me get rid of this.

```
a [shape=none  margin=0 image = "circle.png" fillcolor=blue label=""];
```

What I did is:

```
$txt = print("a [shape=none  margin=0 image = "circle.png" fillcolor=blue label=""]; \n");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$txt = "a [shape=none  margin=0 image = \"router.png\" fillcolor=blue label=\"\"]; \n";`

Comment: "it does not work" is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
print $txt = 'a [shape=none  margin=0 image = "circle.png" fillcolor=blue label=""]';
```